# How to split a list of strings based on delimiter string that ends with specific character in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, split

I have a text which contains many lines.

I want to split it based on string which ends with specific character.

For Ex:
My text contains below data

```
Hi
I'm here:
London
UK
USA
Where are you:
here 
there
what will you do:
something
somethin2
```

I want to split this text into a list with delimiter as a string that ends with

colon - **:**

In this case the final result list would be 
`[ Hi, London UK USA, here there, something somethin2 ]`
How do I do that in python?

I'm aware that we can split with a single character or some other string which is common delimiter. But what to do in this case?

Comment: it looks like what you want to do is iterate over the text as a list of lines, appending them to each other inside the loop and then each time a colon appears add the lines you've previously iterated over to the list, clearing whatever string you use for appending in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(content.split('\n'), key=lambda x:x.endswith(':'))]
final_result = [' '.join(b) for a, b in data if not a]
```

Output:

```
['Hi', 'London UK USA', 'here there', 'something somethin2']
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Got what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of how this can be done.

Note: Easier to understand but far less efficient than @Ajax1234 's answer.

```
text = '''Hi
I'm here:
London
UK
USA
Where are you:
here 
there
what will you do:
something
somethin2'''

# add comma if there is ':' or else insert the line
output = [line.strip() if ':' not in line else ',' for line in text.split('\n')] 

# join the list on space
output = ' '.join(output) 

# split back into list on ',' and trim the white spaces
output = [item.strip() for item in output.split(',')]

print(output)
```

Outputs:

```
['Hi', 'London UK USA', 'here there', 'something somethin2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex split:

```
>>> import re
>>> [s.strip().replace('\n',' ') for s in re.split(r'^.*:$',txt, flags=re.M)] 
['Hi', 'London UK USA', 'here there', 'something somethin2']
```

The regex `^.*:$` finds full lines ending in a `:`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NbxKqM/1/)

And `re.splits` splits the string on that pattern and deletes the delimiting line. Then replace `\n` with `' '` in each string block and you have the desired output.